# how to use mock json Database File in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, mocking

I have to make a **UnitTest** on predefined data by creating a mock JSON database file, and validate that the application returns the correct information.
here is my app, with the function **getUsers:**

```
    from flask import Flask 

app = Flask(__name__)  


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"   

@app.route("/users")
def getUsers():
    # Opening JSON file
    f = open('users.json')  # users.json is the Database
    data = json.load(f)
    for value in data.values():
        value.pop('id')
    result_dict = json.dumps(data)
    return result_dict
```

i have tried to mock like this:

```
@patch('hello.getUsers')
def test_users(MockBlog):
    getUsers = MockBlog()      
    getUsers.return_value = requests.get('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/MosenzonTal/demo/db').json()
    response = getUsers()
    print(response)
```

i have to validate getUsers output from the fake db.
the response is:
**{'test_user1': {'id': 'tes1t', 'name': 'Test User 1', 'favorite_color': 'Black'}**
but the id of the user wasn't filtered out as i expected. WHY? shouldnt that code apply getUsers on the fake db?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are changing the return value of `MockBlog` to the requests response of https://my-json-server.typicode.com/MosenzonTal/demo/db, you will get the data stored there (that includes the id).